# C function call produces different result than C++ function call

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    while(1) {
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)  // That number doesnt actually work, only works with -32768 (which checks to see if the key is pressed down)
                printf("%c\n",i); // When using -32768, it prints the key if it is held down about 20 times
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

so -32767 doesnt work in that C code, but I have this C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char i;
    while (1) {
        for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)  // works as intended, prints the pressed key letter (doesnt have to be held down)
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which works with -32767. This is very confusing as both of these are being ran on the same computer with the same command: `clang++ test.c`

Output of C with -32768(pressing A):

```
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
```

output of C++ code with -32767:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

Output of C code with -32767:
(Nothing)

Comment: Your second example uses `char i;` instead, this is a significant difference because your loop goes beyond `CHAR_MAX`. Try again with `int i;`

Comment: Can you also edit your question to describe what key you press and what output you receive in each case

Comment: You should probably read the "Return value" and "Remarks" section of [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx). The only fully defined results are `0` and *non-zero*.

Comment: @M.M The C implementation is the one that does not work.

Comment: Why are you comparing against these specific values? What does the documentation tell you to do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because `-32767` means a key has been pressed, and `-32768` means a key is being held down.

Comment: @Vikaton you're just making that up

Comment: Yes, you are making that up. You have not understood the documentation at all. Have you even read the documentation? If so, where does it say that?

Comment: @M.M @DavidHeffernan I may be wrong, but that's what it appears to do in the C++ code, if `GetAsyncKeyState(ascii_key_pressed) == -32767` then it was pressed, but Ill reread the documentation more thoroughly I guess.

Comment: It's as @M.M says. Test `<0` to see if the key is down. That's it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the documentation, the most significant bit checks to see if the key is being held down, I'm looking for the lest significant bit which checks if "the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState" which in the C++ code is -32767, and the most significant is -32728 (since it prints the letter if its being held down!). I may be interpreting this wrong and I'm sorry but I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: Test LSB with `GetAsyncKeyState() & 1 == 1`. You are testing all bits, not just one. But LSB test is not reliable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan added that to the C code, no such luck, added it to the C++ code, as expected, it worked. :/ I think I'm just going to have to find a different method to catch keys that have been pressed

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation of GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. **However, you should not rely on this last behavior**; for more information, see the Remarks.

This says that it is not reliable to treat `-32768` differently to `-32767`. It also says nothing about all of the bits in between, but your code is assuming they are `1` bits without justification.

To be reliable, your code should only do the following tests on the return value:

- `>= 0` - key currently up, or info unavailable
- `< 0` - key currently down

Comment: `< 0` is the same as `-32768`, checks to see if a key is being held down. `>=0` just prints out all the characters during the loop without anything being pressed, all I want is for `-32767` to work or some other reliable value to check if a key has been pressed in the C implementation.

Comment: @Vikaton please read the documentation. It explains that there is no reliable way to check if the key was pressed but is no longer down, using this function.

Comment: This is an absolute classic. You are claiming that all negative numbers are equal to `-32768`. One of the all time greats.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan heh, it looks that way at first, but I think he was trying to say that if he changed his code to read `< 0` instead of `-32768` then he observed the same behaviour

Comment: @Vikaton The documentation goes on to say that the least significant bit set was only reliable in 16 bit Windows. Now, other multitasking applications calling the function will reset the bit. If you rely on that bit your program will fail depending on what else is running.

Answer (score 3):

Your code relies on implementation-defined behavior. It appears that your C compiler is using unsigned `char`s, while your C++ compiler uses signed ones. That is why the nested loop in C goes all the way to 190, while the same loop in C++ wraps around to zero upon reaching 128.

You can fix this by making the type of `i` an `unsigned char` in both implementations. You could also make `i` an `int`, and add a cast to `char` in the call of `GetAsyncKeyState` function.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that `clang++ test.c` would select plain char as unsigned for a Windows target; perhaps it is just looping infinitely until the key pressed, or something

Answer (score 1):

See this topic:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/141404/
-32767 is actually 1000 0000 0000 0001 in binary, when you compare the returned value from GetAsyncKeyState(i), you're basically asking if only the left and right bits are on, but as it is said in the link above, the bits 1-14 may not always be zero.
A more proper expression would be like that:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & -32767)
```

or maybe use a hex literal instead:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason why the C implementation didnt work was because I was manually executing `./a` in the mingw32 terminal and for some reason it didn't print anything until after alot of keys have been pressed, so I just executed `a.exe` by double-clicking and it worked, this has been a very weird experience :/